# Jquery wrap()- chracter before forward slash `/`

Tags: javascript, jquery

Before the forward slash `/` could I `wrap()` the character inside the HTML tag?  I want to wrap all the characters into a HTML element which are before the the `/`

jQuery snippet:

```
var x = jQuery('.elementor-drop-cap-yes p').contents().filter(function(){
  return this.nodeType === 3
}).wrap('<span class="drop-caps" />');
```

Current result:

```html
<p>
  <span class="a">
    <span class="b">1</span>
  </span>
  0/10
</p>
```

Expected result:

```html
<p>
  <span class="a">
    <span class="b">1</span>
  </span>
  <div class="c">
    <b class="d">0</b>/10
  <div>
</p>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below simple logic to achieve the html wrapping

```js
jQuery(function(){
  jQuery('.elementor-drop-cap-yes p').each(function(){
     var $div = jQuery('<div/>');
     var $children = $(this).children();
     $div.append($children);
     var text = jQuery(this).text();
     if(text.indexOf('/')>=0) {
        var index = text.indexOf('/');
        //console.log(index);
        var textParts = text.substring(0, index);
        var newHTML = '<div class="c"><b class="d">' + text.substring(0, index) +'</b>' + text.substring(index, text.length) + '</div>';
        jQuery(this).empty().append($children).append(newHTML);
     }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="elementor-drop-cap-yes">
<p>
    <span class="a">
         <span class="b">1</span>
     </span>
    0/10
</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! for prominent solution. I also need forward slash. As you can see `/` has been removed

Comment: Thanks @bhusahn you save my day!

Comment: happy to help you :)

Comment: i have updated my answer using substring instead of split which will be more prominent. please take a look

Comment: I've added the anchor tag inside the HTML and script is removing the anchor tag. can you please check